# Angular JS: Watch changes in a variable made in FOO directive to reflect in BAR directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am currently working on extending the UX of [Angular Typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I made it possible for the results list not to get cleared on `input` `.blur` and remain in the DOM until the query changes.

But this way the results do not disappear. And I want to bind the `input.blur()` event to the variable, that is later on passed to the `scope` that has control over the `typeahead-popup.html` module.

Here's the adapted relevant-code of what I currently have:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.typeahead', ['ui.bootstrap.position'])
    .directive('typeahead', ['$compile', '$parse', '$q', '$timeout', '$document', '$window', '$rootScope', '$position', 'typeaheadParser',
        function($compile, $parse, $q, $timeout, $document, $window, $rootScope, $position, typeaheadParser) {
            return {
                link: function(originalScope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
                    var isBlurred;
                    //some irrelevant library code

                    //on this event I change isBlurred;
                    element.bind('blur', function() {
                        //irrelevant functionality
                        isBlurred = true;
                    });

                    element.bind('focus', function() {
                        isBlurred = false;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }])


    .directive('typeaheadPopup', function() {
        return {
            scope {
                //<irrelevant other variables>
                isBlurred: '='
            }
        },
        replace: true,
        //<irrelevant code>
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //<irrelevant other functions that have access to the scope and apply params at the DOM element>
            scope.$watch('isBlurred', function() {
                console.log(isBlurred)
            });

        });
    })

});
```

Directive `typeaheadPopup` has control over the relevant DOM elements. Therefore the variable change from the `.blur` and `.focus` events on the input. But this doesn't happen. I just get `wasBlurred is not defined`.

**Question:**
How do I adjust the code in a way so that variable change that happens in `typeahead` directive is reflected properly within `typeaheadPopup` directive?

Comment: Can you create a plunker containing the whole module? so that we know what currently works and not

Comment: "Creating Directives that Communicate"  section from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you have this structure `<input type="text" uib-typeahead typeahead-popup/>` or this one `<input type="text" uib-typeahead /> <typeahead-popup>`?

Comment: Please check edited question

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l7qVulisaTVfCdzyVJkD?p=preview) with ui-bootstrap.

Here is an integration with ui-bootstrap and a close button control. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l7qVulisaTVfCdzyVJkD?p=preview)

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SAqFtg6ARB7XNHnFnJQA?p=preview) with the code you gave and the question about how to communicate between directives.

Your `isBlurred` variable needs to be assigned to the scope :
`originalScope.isBlurred;`

Blur and focus are not part of the ngModelOptions that will trigger the scope to automaticaly change. You need to trigger it manualy.

```
element.on('blur', function() {
   originalScope.$apply(function(){
      originalScope.isBlurred = true;
   });
});
```

Now your isBlurred is linked to the scope and that it will update with your  custom events, you can forward it to your `typeaheadPopup` directive this way  :

`<input type="text" ng-model="name" typeahead typeahead-popup="isBlurred">`

Define a isolated scope in your typeaheadPopup :

```
scope :  {
    isBlurred: '=typeaheadPopup'
}
```

There it is :  your isBlurred variable is accessible and will automatically be updated in your directive. No need for a `$watch`.  But you'll need one if you want to trigger an event when it changes :

```
scope.$watch('isBlurred', function() {
     alert("inside typeaheadPopup directive" + scope.isBlurred)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is for all **non-Angular event-handlers** (in your case it's `element.bind`) you should call **scope.$apply** (or **scope.$digest**) **to run the digest cycle** and synchronise the values.

So for your case you either do manual call:

```
element.on('blur', function() {
    originalScope.isBlurred = true;    
    originalScope.$apply();
});
```

or to run Angular method that will do it for you, for example $timeout:

```
element.on('blur', function() {
    $timeout(function(){
       originalScope.isBlurred = true;
    });
});
```

$timeout sometimes is needed like a hack to integrate 3rd party non-Angular libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You need something like this [demo](http://jsbin.com/cupedipumu/2/edit?html,css,js,output) right? So you need to assign a two-way bounded scope in each directive like this

```
scope: {
  model: "="
},
```

then set both of them with the same model

```
<body ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
   <foo model='vm.foobar'></foo>
   <bar model='vm.foobar'></bar>
</body>
```

so `MainController`'s foobar is set two-way bounded to foo and bar's scope, so technically, they share the same model and have every changes the model have.

please see the demo for the full code

Answer (score 0):

If you can nest your directives, or use one as an attribute on the other, then they are able to communicate more cleanly. If they exist on the same level, then I believe some injected share state is you best bet.

If possible, nest the directives and make them communicate as described under "Creating Directives that Communicate" (at the bottom) of the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Example:

```
angular.module('foo', [])
.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    controller: function() {
      this.someFunction = function(pane) {
      };
    }
  };
})
.directive('child', function() {
  return {
    require: '^^parent',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {
      parentCtrl.someFunction();
    }
  };
});
```